# Java speed comparison between HashMap and ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I wonder if there are any comparison between searching elements in Hashmap vs ArrayList. The case which I encountered looks as follow: I'll have small amount of elements (usually 4-6 probably up to 10). I've integer Id of such element and I'll get a lot of calls which will search elements using id and execute some method on this element. 
It looks like good usecase for hashmap however I started to wonder if linear collection like ArrayList wouldn't be better here. For example because of CPU cache. And also to use search on map I need autoboxing to create Integer from primitive.
Question is for this case better is do linear search and comparison of primitive ints or rather stick to hashmap?

Comment: If you have only 10 elements, it doesn't matter what you use

Comment: The best way to get results relevant to your case would be to test it yourself. That being said *up to 10* elements is a relatively tiny number of elements. Unless you're searching those 10 elements many times.

Comment: As I mentioned there will be a lot of calls for it. That's why I'm searching any resources for such tests. I can do some naive time measurements but in full system it might behave differently. That's why I'm asking if there are any analyses for Java. I'm pretty sure that I saw such discussions for C++ collections.
@Aleksandr so In your opinion if I need to do 200-300k search autoboxing is not an issue?

Comment: @TheTosters you should provide a code snippet of both intended use cases. And also 300k searches in how much time? As soon as possible? In a minute?
Moreover, are you asking this because you have hit a bottleneck or just out of curiosity?

Comment: Also, how big are your objects?

Comment: I'm asking it before write and integrate into system. Size of object doesn't really matter since java returns you reference not a copy of object. I expect 200-300k search in about 10-15 min. It will not be constantly distributed over time but rather in short bursts. But I don't see point in those questions, it's not related to core question.

Comment: Size of the object does matter. If it's very big, it won't fit in the cache, thus making this questing useless. Also, if the performance is really such a problem for you, you should write your own data structure similar to a map, but which will use primitives as a key (or you can try iterating a plain old array).

Comment: @Aleksandr an object not fitting into a CPU cache would be rather unusual, but anyway, a CPU cache doesn’t load entire objects, but only cache lines for the actually accessed data. For small objects, this may even affect memory not belonging to the object…

Comment: There are also libraries like fastutil or trove that allows you to create maps with primitive keys, but probably you just don't need that much performance as difference will be close to 0 for few elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your ids are not index based than an ArrayList#get will be `O(n)` (you have to iterate over the elements) while a HashMap#get will be `O(1)`.

Comment: Speed is not complexity, the OP is not discussing "sufficiently large N" but a collection of size 4-10.

Comment: If elements will have index access there would be no question about it. I need to perform a search using ID not index based.

Comment: @TheTosters since you said that the ID is an integer, it might be possible that it can be mapped to a list index, we can’t know. At least, you can always sort the list by index and have O(log n) time complexity. Not that it matters much for up to ten elements…

Comment: @Holger Yep, bisearch is an option. Even if Id are not continuous and can't be used as a direct index. However question still apply if multiple access to ArrayList will be faster for such approach than single access to HashMap. Looks like I need to do just blind tests to see if there is any significant difference. I didn't found any more information on net.